# How to add parameters to current URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a logic where I allow sorting on price and relevance. I am doing this by passing parameters to controller. My URL has a parameter - 'sort' which can have a value - 'price_lowest' or 'default'.
The links looks like:

```
<a href="<%= request.fullpath + '&sort=price_lowest' %>">lowest prices</a> | 
<a href="<%= request.fullpath + '&sort=default' %>">relevance</a>
```

problem with the above code is that it "adds" parameters and does not "replace" them. I want to replace the value of &sort= parameter without adding a new value. E.g. I don't want :

```
../&sort=price_lowest&sort=price_lowest&sort=default
```

With the current logic - I am getting the above behaviour. Any suggestions ?

Comment: you should really avoid this kind of hacks. Named routes are made to answer your needs

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you only need one cgi param and want to stay on the same page, this is very simple to achieve:

```
<%= link_to "lowest prices", :sort => "price_lowest" %>
```

However, if you have more than one, you need some logic to keep old ones. It'd probably be best extracted to a helper, but essentially you could do something like this to keep the other params..

```
<%= link_to "lowest prices", :sort => "price_lowest", :other_param => params[:other] %>
```

Named routes will only really help you here if you need to go to another page.

Comment: This removes the existing parameters. I end up with - http://localhost:3000/view?sort=price_lowest - all other previous parameters are lost.

Comment: Can you elaborate your solution a bit ?

Comment: As I said in the answer, if you have more than the one param, you'll need to have some logic to keep the ones you're not setting. A helper is definitely the best place for something like this. Here's a (potentially flawed, poorly written and untested) example of how to achieve that: https://raw.github.com/gist/e22343babcb76381304c/7a419e8f5333fc34a52df914d9794078fa5f1af5/gistfile1.txt

Comment: And if you only need the url you can use `url_for params.merge( sort: 'price_lowest' )`

Comment: Does not work, loses all other params

Comment: @FabiandePabian Using `params.merge( sort: "price_lowest" )` does work and keeps the existing params. If you're not seeing that, something else is going wrong with your code. _NOTE: For Rails 5, you'll need to use `request.params.merge`._

Comment: @JoshuaPinter as per the next answer it works indeed. But the answer we are commenting on loses all other params but the one provided to `link_to`

Comment: @FabiandePabian Damn, you're right. Sorry, must have been cross-eyed looking at the answers. I thought you were commenting on my comment, not the answer. :)

Comment: And if you need to add a `class` for instance: `link_to "lowest prices", { sort: "price_lowest" }, class: "button"`

Answer (score 67):

In order to preserve the params I did this:

```
<%= link_to 'Date', params.merge(sort: "end_date") %>
```

However the url will be ugly.

**UPDATE**

For Rails 5 use:

```
<%= link_to 'Date', request.params.merge(sort: "end_date") %>
```

Comment: why not `<%= link_to 'Date', params.merge(:sort => "end_date") %>` btw your name looks interesting , like Chinese...

Comment: In rails 5 you need to use request.params
<%= link_to 'Date', request.params.merge(:sort => "end_date") %>

Comment: For Rails 5, https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26289 is a good read, with an explanation of the risks and examples of solutions.

Answer (score 13):

If a path is not passed to the `link_to` method, the current `params` are assumed. In Rails 3.2, this is the most elegant method for adding or modifying parameters in a URL:

```
<%= link_to 'lowest prices', params.merge(sort: 'end_date') %>
<%= link_to 'relevance', params.merge(sort: 'default') %>
```

`params` is a Ruby hash. Using merge will either add a key or replace the value of a key. If you pass `nil` as the value of a key, it will remove that key/value pair from the hash.

```
<%= link_to 'relevance', params.merge(sort: nil) %>
```

Cite:

- link_to http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to
- url_for
  http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for

Comment: Combined with the `active_link_to` Gem and you'll also have nice active classes on your filters. - https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to

Comment: You should update your answer for strong parameters and using `params.permit!` in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

**My working solution on Rails 3.1**
of course, it's hardcode, and has to be refactored.

*item model*

```
  def self.get(field,value)
    where(field=>value)
  end
```

*items controller*

```
@items=Item.all
 if params[:enabled]
  @items=@items.get(:enabled, params[:enabled])
end
if params[:section]
  @items=@items.get(:section_id, params[:section])
end
```

*items helper*

```
def filter_link(text, filters={}, html_options={})
  trigger=0
  params_to_keep = [:section, :enabled]
  params_to_keep.each do |param|
    if filters[param].to_s==params[param] && filters[param].to_s!="clear" || filters[param].to_s=="clear"&&params[param].nil?
      trigger=1
    end
    if filters[param]=="clear"
      filters.delete(param)
    else
      filters[param]=params[param] if filters[param].nil?
    end
  end
  html_options[:class]= 'current' if trigger==1
  link_to text, filters, html_options
end
```

*items index.html.erb*

```
<%= filter_link 'All sections',{:section=>"clear"} %>
<% @sections.each do |section| %>
   <%= filter_link section.title, {:section => section} %>
<% end %>

<%= filter_link "All items", {:enabled=>"clear"} %>
<%= filter_link "In stock", :enabled=>true %>
<%= filter_link "Not in stock", :enabled=>false %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite the answer to the question that you're asking, but have you thought about using the [Sorted gem](https://github.com/mynameisrufus/sorted) to handle your sorting logic and view links?